# Count duplicate values in array php

Tags: php, arrays, count

Firstly thanks in advance :)

I write a code like this way:

```
$data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,5];

$result = max(array_count_values($data));

if($result > 1) {
  echo 'Duplicate items were found!';
}else{
  echo 'No Duplicate';
}
```

This code works perfectly but when I get data from the server-side like :

```
$getValue = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,5';
$data = [$getValue];

$result = max(array_count_values($data));

if($result > 1) {
  echo 'Duplicate items were found!';
}else{
  echo 'No Duplicate';
}
```

code not working, anyone please help me here to sort out.

Comment: use `$data = explode(',', $getValue)` instead of `$data = [$getValue]`.

Comment: `$data` contains _one_ element with `'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,5'` as value in your second code

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$getValue = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,5';
$data = [$getValue];
$data = explode(',', $data[0]);
$result = max(array_count_values($data));

if($result > 1) {
  echo 'Duplicate items were found!';
}else{
  echo 'No Duplicate';
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `$data = [$getValue];`? you override `$data` just after with `$data[0]`.

Comment: I dont know ! bstha wrote that line. I think he has that kind of data format

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$getValue` is a string, and using `$data = [$getValue];` will create an array with that single entry and using [max](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) will return 1 yielding "No Duplicate"

What you could do is check if the variable `$getValue` is a string, use explode and remove the empty entries.

For this you could use for example [array_filter](https://www.php.net/array_filter) and you can see the documentation what this will remove when using it without a callback.

```
$getValue = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,5';
if (is_string($getValue)) {
    $result = max(array_count_values(array_filter(explode(',', $getValue))));
}
if ($result > 1) {
    echo 'Duplicate items were found!';
} else {
    echo 'No Duplicate';
}
```

Output

```
Duplicate items were found!
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/3M8eH).